# A bash script to rename files from different directories at once

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rename

If I have a directory named `/all_images`, and inside this directory there's a ton of directories, all the directories named as `dish_num` as shown below. and inside each dish directory, there's one image named `rgb.png`. How can i rename all the image files to be the name of its directory.

#### Before

```
|
├── dish_1
│   └── rgb.png
├── dish_2
│   └── rgb.png
├── dish_3
│   └── rgb.png
├── dish_4
│   └── rgb.png
└── dish_5
    └── rgb.png
```

#### After

```
|
├── dish_1
│   └── dish_1.png
├── dish_2
│   └── dish_2.png
├── dish_3
│   └── dish_3.png
├── dish_4
│   └── dish_4.png
└── dish_5
    └── dish_5.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple shell loop should suffice:

```
for d in dish_*; do 
  echo mv "$d/rgb.png" "$d/$d.png"
done
```

or (if you need to run it from somewhere other than the containing directory)

```
for d in path/to/dish_*; do 
  f="${d##*/}.png"
  echo mv "$d/rgb.png" "$d/$f"
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is going to do the right thing.

---

If you wanted to get fancy, you could do something like this with GNU `parallel`:

```
parallel echo mv {}/rgb.png {}/{/.}.png ::: path/to/dish_*
```

or (if the argument list is too long)

```
printf '%s\0' path/to/dish_* | parallel --null echo mv {}/rgb.png {}/{/.}.png
```